# Open 1 modal with two different links

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a page, with a modal. Now I have a table on that page. I want to include a link in each row of the table that opens that same modal, and then put different content in it using jQuery.

The problem I'm having is in the modals. When I give 2 links the id `code`, and do the following in jQUery:

```
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
    $("#code").click(function()
      {
        $("#CodeModal").modal('show')
      });
  });
```

Only the first link opens the modal.

I have also tried `data-toggle`, but that resulted in no links being able the open the modal.

Is there a way to make this possible? If so, how to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Id` must be unique. You can assign the same class to the links and do this:

```
$(".code").click(function()
{
    $("#CodeModal").modal('show')
});
```